# Best way to define multiple dictionary in one line versus many lines

Tags: python

Which method is better and why?

```
a = dict() 
b = dict()
c = dict()
```

or

```
a, b, c = dict(), dict(), dict()
```

All three dictionaries will have different keys and are for different purpose.

Comment: It's probably a question of style

Comment: Well first you shouldn't have three dictionaries with single-letter names... This is not a useful thing to answer in the generic case, read PEP-8 and do whatever feels good within that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All 3 dictionaries will have different keys and are for different purpose ?

**Keep it on different lines** -- they are more readable that way. Readability of a python code matters a lot. That being said, you could:

```
a = {}   # or dict(..)
b = {}
c = {}
```

Note: This doesn't mean you **can not** do it in a single line. I am guilty of doing it myself.

**Update**: It seems there are people who prefer an explicit `dict()` over implicit `{}`. I guess the former is slightly more readable. Personally, I'm someone who'd go out of my way to delete `dict()` and replace with `{}` whenever I see one.

Comment: FWIW, there are a large number of "pythonistas" who prefer `dict()` to `{}` (for readability reasons).  Personally, It doesn't make much difference to me ...